# Can you switch places with your mount using bait and switch?

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat, battle-master

If you made a Battle Master fighter and used Bait and Switch to switch places with your mount, would the mount or rider benefit from the effect of Bait and Switch?

What would the cost be? Does this work from a RAW perspective? Does this have any substantial effect on the game?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 20):

### Probably hilarity

Let's just look over the scenario and then the requirements. We have our fighter who is directly above their horse (substitute for any other mount, I'm just specifying for ease).

Then, the fighter needs to be within 5 ft of the other creature, with no requirements on being vertical or not. The fighter needs to spend at least 5 feet of movement, which they can have available. There's actually an argument you need to spend [half your movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountingandDismounting) to dismount the horse, but that's written for normal dismounting, so we'll leave that to your DM to decide. Willingness and the horse not being incapacitated we'll take as good.

Now to the effect. The fighter and horse swap places. Since the fighter was above the horse and the horse on the ground, the horse is now above the fighter and the fighter on the ground. The generous (and hilarious) interpretation is that the fighter is now carrying the horse, since it was previously being carried. Hope they have the carrying capacity for it. Either way, one of them (fighter's choice) gets to have the superiority die added to their AC for a round.

> Roll the superiority die. Until the start of your next turn, you or the other creature (your choice) gains a bonus to AC equal to the number rolled.
>
> — [Bait and Switch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster), *Player's Handbook*

Answer (score 7):

### It is your choice whether the mount or you benefits from the bonus.

[Bait and Switch:](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/fighter#BaitandSwitch)

> When you’re within 5 feet of a creature on your turn, you can expend one superiority die and switch places with that creature, provided you spend at least 5 feet of movement and the creature is willing and isn’t incapacitated.  [...] Roll the superiority die. Until [...] you or the other creature (your choice) gains a bonus [...]

The cost is one superiority die, you need to spend at least 5 feet of movement, be within 5 feet of the mount on your turn, and the mount needs to be willing and not incapacitated. You choose whether you or the mount receives the bonus.

When you fulfill the requirements, you can use Bait and Switch and the mount is a valid target as a creature. If you are mounted — you will also have to dismount.